# two different hours subtraction Angular 6

Tags: angular6, momentjs, calculation

I am trying to do how to subtract two different hours that is captured:

Here is TS code

```js
clockingIn() {
    var dt = new Date()
    this.clockedIn= new Date().getHours()+':'+ new Date().getMinutes()+':'+ new Date().getSeconds();
    console.log('clockin', this.clockedIn);
    this.disableClockIn = true;
    this.disableClockOut = false;
}

clockingOut() {
    var dt2 = new Date();
    this.clockedOut= new Date().getHours()+':'+ new Date().getMinutes()+':'+ new Date().getSeconds();
    console.log('clockout', this.clockedOut);
    this.disableClockIn = false;
    this.disableClockOut = true;
}

subtraction() {
    var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
    var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

    var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
}

//table 

test() {
    const data = {
      dateClock: this.dateobj(),
      Job: this.selectedJob,
      clockI: this.clockedIn,
      clockO:  this.clockedOut,
      Hoursworked: this.subtraction()
    };

    this.dataSource.data.push(data);
    this.refresh();
    console.log(this.dataSource);
}
```

So this is a clock in and Clock out.

I want these two can calculate (Clock Out - Clock In) to see the difference of two hours in the table that I made. So this way, I can see the diff time between Clock Out and Clock In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your duration will be calculated in `subtraction` function.

Below changes will get the result :

```js
subtraction() {
    var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
    var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";
    // I have set to minutes. Change unit as per your requirement by 
    // referring doc given as reference
    var unit = 'm'; 

    return moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"), unit);
}
```

[Moment.js duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating)